# Is it safe to clean my iMac's screen with household products?

Tags: mac, cleaning

Self explanatory. 21.5 inch iMac, late 2009.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vinegar and water, half and half, gentle circular motions with a clean cotton t-shirt. Make sure not to use too much liquid as it can drip.

Comment: plain white vinegar, if possible.  red wine vinegar should be saved for your salad.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I typically clean any LCD displays I have with a slightly damp microfiber cloth.  You'll definitely want to use something soft--I've seen quotes online that say nothing rougher than a t-shirt.

I have used Windex before as well, but I noticed slight discoloration on my monitor for several minutes (after which the effect faded).

Comment: most Windex formulas contain ammonia -- which is not good for your screen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

I clean my LCD-screens with a very diluted water/dishwasher-liquid solutions and a soft cloth I got with my glasses.

I have been doing this for over 10 years and never had any problems.

Comment: I trust you're referring to the stuff for washing dishes in the sink, not the nasty stuff for automatic dishwashers?

Comment: @JRobert - You are quite correct